# Jquery datatable how to disable specific row while drag & drop?

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
rowReorder: {
            dataSrc: 'tr'
        },
```

I'm using the rowReorder for drag & drop, but I need to disable specific row from dragging and changing its order, How to do that?

Comment: Possible answer here: [datatables forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59609/jquery-datatables-rowreorder-disable-row-from-being-sorted-reordered)

Comment: Does this example do what you want?   "Garret Winters" can't be dragged.   http://live.datatables.net/nanaqowi/7/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
rowReorder: {
                dataSrc: 'tr',
                selector: 'td.reorder',
            },
columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: 0,
                    className: 'reorder',
                    createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData) {
var selector = $(td).parents('tr').find('.reorder');
                            selector.addClass('reorder-disabled');
                            selector.removeClass('reorder');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
```